# Stripe Payment - Change customer subscription's amount

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Here, I am explaining you what is my requirement. I am using Stripe Payment Gateway API and PHP langauge. I have a plan - "**#planname**" where our customer can subscribe with us but payment vary in three mode -

```
First Month - Trial

Second Month - $50 USD
```

and from `Third Month - $20 USD` to continue.

How can I do this?

Comment: I almost flagged this as spam…

Comment: What's stopping you from simply billing the clients that way?